# Several question about understanding of input data for input of the contract

Tags: go-ethereum

I need to get input data from transaction. Here is original question [Here is original question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34030/how-to-obtain-contract-method-data), [here is official documentation which gives some insights](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html).

At the first sight it should be a big deal. We have a string, we know types and their order, we know how much chars each types takes - parse it and that's all. However when I dig dipper things become more complicated. Here is the list of questions I would like to address:

1. Why uint256 doesn't contain 256 bytes (512 chars as I exact here)?
2. Why is bytes10 padded to 32 bytes when I expect to see here 10
   bytes(20 symbols)?
3. Why values in most cases right aligned, in some
   cases - left aligned?
4. What is the head and tail? How to calculate
   them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html gives you the full details. As to your individual questions:

1. `uint256` is 256 **bits**, so it's 32 bytes, or 64 characters in hexadecimal.
2. `bytes10`, like all the various sizes of `bytes`, is encoded as a length followed by a value, and then the entire thing is right-padded to be a multiple of 256 bits:

> `bytes`, of length `k` (which is assumed to be of type `uint256`):
>
> `enc(X) = enc(k) pad_right(X)`, i.e. the number of bytes is encoded as a
>   `uint256` followed by the actual value of `X` as a byte sequence, followed
>   by the minimum number of zero-bytes such that `len(enc(X))` is a
>   multiple of 32.

3. Perhaps #2 answered this. Numbers are left-padded, as you would expect for big-endian encoding. `bytes` types, however, are right-padded. (The length prefix tells you how many bytes are actually present, so the zeros kind of make sense on the right in that case. They're just there for alignment purposes.)
4. The documentation explains this. The head is the first part of the encoding, and the tail is the rest. In the case of scalar types, there is no tail. In the case of static arrays, the head is the first element, and the tail is the rest. (Recursively, the next head is the next element, etc.) For dynamic arrays, the head is the offset at which its data starts.

Comment: 1. Aha! Then it is example from doc confused me -- there is uint32 which also encoded with 64 chars. It looks like all dimensional params uint<T> padded to the highest value. At the same time uint with smaller bit size should be used by ethereum. Does it mean value padded to uint256  only for representation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "only for representation." It's padded as part of ABI-encoding.

Comment: In my understanding, different uint types serves the aim to minimize amount of memory on stack to hold params and variables. In case all variety of uint at the end padded to it highest representation what is the point to have them?

Comment: 4. I didn't get it. What is behind concept of head and tails? In the sample which started with words "If we wanted to call sam " head represents location of data. Why don't we omit it and knowing the order of params use first symbol as a size of arguments?

Comment: I don't really want to speculate as to the reason ABI was designed the way it was, but I assume it was to make random access of parameters easier. If I understand your proposal correctly, it would require always accessing the parameters starting at the beginning, since there would be no way to find the start of a parameter that was preceded by a dynamic array.

Comment: I see, it might be a good reason behind it. Don't you mind to go a bit further and help understand how this offset works? In the example I mentioned "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060" represents the location of data of the first parameter as an offset from the beginning of argument list. Now I thinking on how this number can help me jump into this first argument

Comment: 0x60 is 96 in decimal. That's the location (in bytes) of the data portion of the first parameter. (32 bytes for that location, 32 bytes for the boolean second parameter, and 32 bytes for the location of the third parameter data. 32+32+32=96)